# Contracting rational curves on surfaces and getting something non-algebraic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, complex-geometry

Recently I posted an "announcement" on arxiv where I said something to the effect of "this is the first example we know where contracting (a tree of) rational curves from a non-singular algebraic surface (over $\mathbb{C}$) leads to a (normal)  *non-algebraic*  surface." Now that I am writing up the actual paper, I thought that may be I should broaden my knowledge base! So I ask: is there some example of this sort already known?

Remarks:

1. Grauert constructed (in this article:  [mathscinet link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/137127.pdf),  [springerlink](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01441136)) such non-algebraic surfaces by blowing down curves of genus $\geq 2$ (in Section 4.8, Example d) and remarked that he did not know if it is possible (to construct non-algebraic normal surfaces) from blowing down tori.
2. An example of Nagata described in a  [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79215/pathologies-of-analytic-non-algebraic-varieties)  of mine shows that it is indeed possible with tori.
3. In the second paragraph of the first page of  [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372985) ([mathscinet link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/146182.pdf)) Artin mentions an example of Hironaka that shows that "in general there are no numerical criteria equivalent with (algebraic) contractibility of a given curve." Does anyone know what is this example?
4. Happy New Year!

Comment: Check out Schröer's papers http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911004 and http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911119.

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks! But I knew of these (perhaps should have mentioned them in the question) and they do not contain (and as far as I can see, do not shed any light on the construction of) any such examples.

Comment: Algebraic spaces are "algebraic".  It says so right in the name!

Comment: @Jason: OK, I admit it wasn't such a good choice of words :) Would you prefer if I change "something non-algebraic" to "non-algebraic surfaces"?

Comment: @auniket:  Of course I understand what you mean, so my comment is joking.  I think "non-schematic" is a bit more precise than "non-algebraic".